# Scheme function to take only one input values instead of two

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

i have a this function below which to make it print the list you enter (iota 1 10) so prints numbers 1-10 in a list like so (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10). How would i change this to only take one number and still print from 1-(the chosen number) in a list. i just cant get my head around how i should go about this. thanks.

```
(define iota
(lambda(x y)
      (cond((> x y)
            '())
           (else
            (cons x
                  (iota (+ 1 x)y))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same approach, you could count down (instead of up) and use `append`:

```
(define iota2
  (lambda (y)
    (if (< y 1)
        '()
        (append (iota2 (- y 1)) (list y)))))
```

but that's not very effcient.

Why not keep `iota` as is, and use

```
(define iota2
  (lambda (y)
    (iota 1 y)))
```

or use a simple loop (named let):

```
(define iota2
  (lambda (y)
    (let loop ((n 1))
      (if (<= n y)
          (cons n (loop (+ n 1)))
          '()))))
```

Comment: Why is the counting down not so efficient?

Comment: thank-you for that, the first way is the way i need to do it. i cant use the second way as my exercise is to try and write a function called iota. thanks for the help.

Comment: Using `append` is inefficient, as opposed to using `cons`.

Comment: @AdamWilson you could still use the 2nd approach by calling `iota2` `iota`, and the other `iota_impl` or something like that.